# How do you compare a value from jQuery with a fixed number?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do you compare a value from jQuery with a fixed number?

I thought this might work but it doesn't:

```
if (parseInt($("#days").value) > 7) {
            alert("more than one week");
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if #days is an input then you need .val() instead of value

e.g.

```
  if (parseInt($("#days").val()) > 7) {
        alert("more than one week");
   }
```

Comment: Oh for the love of $(#deity).  Thanks!  I can eat lunch now.

Answer (score 9):

As well as [@redsquare 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472917/how-do-you-compare-a-value-from-jquery-with-a-fixed-number#472923) to use `.val()`, you should specify the [radix](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseInt.asp):

```
if (parseInt($("#days").val(), 10) > 7) {
            alert("more than one week");
        }
```

This is because the value could have a leading 0, in which case `parseInt` would interpret the value as octal.